# Access tornado websocket class method from another class

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I'm new to stack overflow, because I regularly found here what I've been looking for. But this time, I don't know how to handle it. I set up a tornado websocket server and would like to access the websocket thread out of another class, but unfortunately, the websocket class requires three different arguments and isn't accessable the usual way.

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):      
        self.loop()

    def on_message(self, message):
        #do something

    def on_close(self):
        #do something else

    def loop(self):
        pass

    def toggle(self):
        #execute

class EventHandler: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.listener()

    def listener(self):        
        def callback(channel):
            wsHandler = WebSocketHandler()
            wsHandler.toggle()

        GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback = callback, bouncetime = 1000)

def main():
    EventHandler()

    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", WebSocketHandler),
    ])
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    server.listen(8888)
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The reason why I have multiple classes is that the server should listen to input events, even if there is no client connected. But I have to transfer the input data via websocket, if there is one. I read about the add_callback method, but I'm not sure whether it's a useful way.

I'm glad about any solution.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seem you figured this out, seeing your answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40655053/794749). You should answer your own question here and then accept it.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit more tricky, because the method should be executed only once; independently of how many clients are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I used `connections = []` (instead of `connections = set()`, because it's accessible through indexing) outside the WebsocketHandler. To add client connections on open to the list I use `connections.append(self)`, to remove them on close `connections.remove(self)`.

Calling the method:

```
if len(connections) > 0:
    connections[0].toggle()
```