# Tornado send message on event

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

Im creating a program in Python that reads a stream of data on an unknown interval. This program also sends this data through websockets.
The program is the server and it sends the received data to the clients.

This is the code of the server now:

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        print 'Websocket opened'

    def open(self):
        print 'New connection'
        self.write_message('Test from server')

    def on_close(self):
        print 'Connection closed'

    def test(self):
        self.write_message("scheduled!")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WebSocketHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = make_app()

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But I want to be able to use `write_message` in this loop:

```
def read_function():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10) # a while loop to simulate the reading
        print 'read serial'
        str = 'string to send'
        # send message here to the clients
```

How am I supposed to do this?

EDIT: will there be a problem with both threads using connections? It seems like it works with 1 connection.

```
def read_function():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5) # a while loop to simulate the reading
        print 'read serial'
        str = 'string to send'
        [client.write_message(str) for client in connections]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target = read_function)
    application = make_app()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    thread.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    thread.join()
```

Comment: You probably also want to remove connections from the set, when they get disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `connections = set()` outside the WebsocketHandler and add every client on opening a connection with `connections.add(self)`. Do not forget to remove them on closing with `connections.remove(self)`.

Now, you are able to access `write_message` out of the websocket thread through: `[client.write_message('#your_message') for client in connections]`

Comment: Thank you! But what would be the best way to run the read_function in another thread? Should i just create a seperate thread with the standard threading library? Thanks

Comment: How is this function called?

Comment: Im just calling it in the main function. It should be a loop checking for input and when theres input it sends the message. But I got it working right now by just putting it on another thread. Im just wondering if its good practise.  I will show the main in the edit.